# Why can __repr__ function use repr() in itself when defining a class?(Python)

Tags: python, repr

```
class Link:

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.rest is not Link.empty:
            rest_repr = ', ' + repr(self.rest)
        else:
            rest_repr = ''
        return 'Link(' + repr(self.first) + rest_repr + ')'
```

I wonder :Is the `repr` function a built-in funciton in Python even though I am defining the __repr__ function?

Answer: the repr() is a bulit-in function. we can use the `repr()` in the `__repr__` function

Comment: Yes, [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) is a built-in function.

Comment: It's not calling `repr` on itself - it's using `repr` on the value stored in the `first` member.

Comment: `repr(self)` would be an infinite recursion, but not on other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.rest is not Link.empty:
            rest_repr = ', ' + repr(self.rest)
```

Look at this piece of code, what do you notice?

Exactly: you are using `repr(self.rest)`, which is equivalent to `self.rest.__repr__()`.

In other words you aren't calling `repr` on an instance of `Link`, but just on an attribute of it. So you aren't calling `Link.__repr__` into its body, don't worry.